# 0B size partition

Tags: centos, partition, fdisk

I have one 0B partition in my disk as the 2nd partition in my CentOS machine.

[image: image fdisk output]

How can I delete it? 
In fdisk , it shows could not delete the partition. 
I want to increase vda1 size using growpart command.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of terminal output. Include it in your question and use the code formatting option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using CentOS live cd over system-rescue-cd ISO for my affected machine .
CentOS live cd allowed to delete that partition and growpart worked fine.